# Ubuntu 19 ubiquity.desktop not launching

Tags: system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu 19. But when I click on Install Ubuntu 19.04 icon nothing happens. It does not open anything.

Comment: Through which means are you installing it? CD, DVD, USB?

Comment: Did you get the installer from here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop too?

Comment: I am using usb.